# I cannot access /root directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, root, su

I have Ubuntu installed in my Mac, not on VM but as a second OS.
When I open my terminal, my username is ubuntu, instead of root.
so it become `ubuntu@nadia-ubuntu:/$`

Then I try to get into root directory.
I type in

```bash
cd root
```

but I got this error

```
bash: cd: root: Permission denied
```

I continue by type in

```bash
su - root
```

Then it asked for password. I type in my log in password. After 5s, I got this:

```
su: Authentication failure
```

How I do get this root privilege?

Actual code below:

```bash
ubuntu@nadias-ubuntu:/$ cd /root
bash: cd: /root: Permission denied
ubuntu@nadias-ubuntu:/$ su -root
su: invalid option -- 'r'
Try 'su --help' for more information.
ubuntu@nadias-ubuntu:/$ su - root
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
ubuntu@nadias-ubuntu:/$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up different concepts which have a similar name.

- **root** (aka **root user** or **superuser**) is the administrator account, and has full access to the machine.
- The **root directory** is `/`, and is the highest (top-most) directory in the filesystem hierarchy.
- The **/root directory** is `/root`, and is the superuser's home directory. It is normally not accessible by non-privileged users ("ubuntu" in your case).

The command `su - root` makes you become the superuser; in order to do so, you have to enter the superuser's password.

If the "ubuntu" user is in the sudoers file, you can use the command `sudo su - root` to become the superuser; in this case, you have to enter the "ubuntu" user's password.

Manpages: [su](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html), [sudo](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo)

Comment: As far as I remember (I've never used Ubuntu - started using Debian before Ubuntu was made - so this is just what I've read/heard), a standard installation of Ubuntu disables the root account and makes you use sudo.

Comment: i could 'log on' as root after using 'su -root' command. Typing whoami giving me 'root' as answer. though I am getting mixed up in the terms used.

Comment: update: i try again 'su - root' and it says 
"su: Authentication failure" 
not sure why 5 hours ago it works  hmm

Answer (score 0):

The "root directory" is /. To get there you type

```
cd /
```

The admin user on Ubuntu (and Linux, and Unix) is named "root" and has a home directory which is in the root directory. To get there you need to type

```
cd /root
```

> su - root .... i type in my log in password

No. The 'su' command switches user and expects the password of the user you are trying to switch to - not the user you are already authenticated as. There is another command which (depending on how your account is configured) allows you to run commands as another user authenticated as with the password for the account you are initially using - 'sudo', e.g.

```
whoami
sudo root whoami
```

These are all very basic questions. Its going to take you a very long time to find your way around of you need to come back here for help with every command you use. There are lots of good tutorials available on the internet - [Paul Sheer's Rute User's Tutorial and Exposition](https://www0.sun.ac.za/hpc/images/d/d5/Rute.pdf) is an old one bit still very good.

If you do have to come back here, one question per post pls.

Comment: very well explanation, and yes i can see I'm getting mixed up in the terminologies.
thanks for the explanation and the shared link!